# Update hidden input field value with another input field value?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update one hidden input field with another visible input field using javascript...

but my code doesn't work for some reason!!

This is my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function process1() {
        document.getElementById("sum_total").value = (document.getElementById("my-item-price").value);
    }
</script>
```

And This Is My form code:

```
<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" id="A1"/></form>

<form><input type="hidden" id="A2" name="A2" value="process1() "/></form>
```

**Update**

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function process1() { 
        document.getElementById("sum_total").value = (document.getElementById("my-item-price").value); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: No `input` has the ID of `sum_total` or `my-item-price`, try changing those to `A1` and `A2`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to update the javascript code. This is my javascript but still doesn't work!!         <script language="javascript">
    function process1() {
    document.getElementById("sum_total").value = (document.getElementById("my-item-price").value);
    }

</script>

Comment: yes, sorry. i've changed it to A1 and A2 but still doesn't work!!

Comment: Erm, still trying to understand the logic. ~_~

Comment: I can't even edit the question now!! I have changed the IDs accordingly but still didn't work!!

Comment: @ Back in a Flash, the idea is to show whatever value is in one input (A1) into another input (A2).

Comment: @RoozFar Try editing again now...

Comment: @Andy, I did change the IDs in my file but still didn't work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

The code you have is bad. You haven´t got `id`s you are looking for in javascript.

Try this:

```
 <script language="javascript">
 function process1(showed) {
    document.getElementById("A2").value = showed.value;
}
</script>

<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" onChange="process1(this)"/></form>

<form><input type="hidden" id="A2" name="A2" value="5" /></form>
```

Comment: Fix the typo in `onChange`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most reliable will be to use onKeyUp rather than onChange or mouse events (onBlur etc.). The following updates the hidden field as each character is entered (I have un-hidden A2 so you can see what is happening).

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function process1() {
    document.getElementById("A2").value = (document.getElementById("A1").value);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" id="A1" onKeyUp="process1()" /></form>
<form><input id="A2" name="A2" value="" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your suggestion was clear and helpful. Thank you for your help bud.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuUj5/)

**HTML**

```
<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" id="A1"/></form>

<form><input type="hidden" id="A2" name="A2" value=""/></form>

<button onClick="process1();">Update</button>
```

**JS**

```
function process1() { 
    document.getElementById("A2").value = document.getElementById("A1").value; 

    alert(document.getElementById("A2").value);
}
```

Comment: plz delete this answer, the asker stated in comments that it's a typo and should be fixing it by now

Comment: guys I already said I've changed the IDs in my file accordingly but didn't work!! the above code is a mistake!

Comment: @ATOzTOA, it doesnt say anything. and i did try your Live Demo but that brings up a pop-up which is not what I am after!

Comment: @RoozFar The pop-up is displaying the value of the hidden input element. If the popup shows the value you entered, then your data is copied over.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind an event to update the value. For example onkeyupevent

    `document.getElementById("A1").onkeyup=function()
    {
        document.getElementById("A2").value = this.value
    };`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value to blank and gave the input an onmouseout (you can use another type if you want) to execute the function and swap values.

```
<script language="javascript">
function process1() {
document.getElementById("A2").value = document.getElementById("A1").value;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>



And This Is My form code:

<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" id="A1"/></form>

<form><input type="text" id="A2" name="A2" value="" onmouseout="process1()" /></form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try the onfocous mouse events and it didn't work so I thought the issue might be from elese where!! The A2 input is hdden so I can't use mouse events! or can I?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
function process1() {
    document.getElementById("A1").value = (document.getElementById("A2").value);
}
</script>
And This Is My form code:
<form><input name="A1" type="text" class="A1" id="A1"/></form>

<form><input type="hidden" id="A2" name="A2" value="process1() "/></form>
<div onClick="process1()">doit</div>
```

does work