# Onclick of link set value of different ID

Tags: javascript

So I've been searching a lot here and on google, but can't seem to find the solution.

Onclick of a link, I need to empty the value of a hidden input field with a certain ID.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('tijdelijke_datum');

document.getElementById("close-popup").onclick = verwijderdatum;

function verwijderdatum() {
  x.value = "";
}
```

```html
<a href="websitelink" id="close-popup">Button value</a>

<input type="hidden" id="tijdelijke_datum" value="{$profile.x}" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update hidden input field value with another input field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709637/update-hidden-input-field-value-with-another-input-field-value)

Comment: Why does `close-popup` have `href="websitelink"`? Also, did your forget to add relevant tags? This looks like you're using some kind of template library: `value="{$profile.x}"`

Comment: @Kiksen unfortunately not, but thanks!

Comment: @connexo I just typed that there instead of the link I was using :-) The value has a smarty value assigned to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its working. Your problem is, since you are using anchor tag, the page navigates to new URL. Try using `Button` instead or setting `href` to `"#"`

```js
var x = document.getElementById('tijdelijke_datum');

document.getElementById("close-popup").onclick = verwijderdatum;
document.getElementById("close-popup2").addEventListener("click", verwijderdatum);

function verwijderdatum() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('tijdelijke_datum').value);
  x.value = "";

  console.log(document.getElementById('tijdelijke_datum').value);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="close-popup">Button value</a>

<br>

<input type="button" id="close-popup2" value="Button value">

<input type="hidden" id="tijdelijke_datum" value="{$profile.x}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript code like below,

```
var x = document.getElementById('tijdelijke_datum');

document.getElementById("close-popup").addEventListener('click', () => {
    event.preventDefault(); // To stop href to navigate, we are using this line
    verwijderdatum();
});

function verwijderdatum() {
    x.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<a href="websitelink" id="close-popup">Button value</a>` to `<a href="javascript:verwijderdatum();" id="close-popup">Button value</a>`

Remove this line:
`document.getElementById("close-popup").onclick = verwijderdatum;`

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery to reset the input field.

use the following code :

```
<script>

  $("#close-popup").click(function(){
    $("#tijdelijke_datum").val("")
  })
</script>
```

Also include a jquery CDN file in your project.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your final code will be as follow :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container text-center">
<a href="websitelink" id="close-popup">Button value</a>
<input type="hidden" id="tijdelijke_datum" value="{$profile.x}" />
</div>


<script>
  $("#close-popup").click(function(){
    $("#tijdelijke_datum").val("")
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I never mind also getting a jquery solution, atleastI can learn from that :-) Although in this case I indeed only need the js, to keep it clean. Thanks though